# Deadlock during insert/update in parallel

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, stored-procedures, apache-camel

I am new to MS SQL Server and I am trying to update the record by incrementing occurrence counter(+1) if data is missing or I freshly insert it with counter value zero '0'.

Moreover my application runs in **parallel** to process each element of data array a[]. When processing array in parallel SQL Server throws deadlock for the same. Though I set transaction isolation level yet the same deadlock is happening on the table. My application is written in Java/Camel/Hibernate.

Stored procedure:

```
IF(@recordCount = 0 OR @recordCount > 1 )
BEGIN
        IF(@chargeAbbreviation IS NOT NULL)
        BEGIN
            set transaction isolation level READ COMMITTED;
            begin transaction;

                    UPDATE  dbo.SLG_Charge_Abbreviation_Missing_Report WITH (UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK)
                        SET     dbo.SLG_Charge_Abbreviation_Missing_Report.Occurrence_Count+=1,dbo.SLG_Charge_Abbreviation_Missing_Report.ModifiedAt=GETDATE()
                        WHERE   dbo.SLG_Charge_Abbreviation_Missing_Report.Jurisdiction_ID = @jurisdictionId AND
                                UPPER(dbo.SLG_Charge_Abbreviation_Missing_Report.Charge_Abbreviation) = @chargeAbbreviation AND 
                                (UPPER(dbo.SLG_Charge_Abbreviation_Missing_Report.Statute_Code) = @statuteCode OR (dbo.SLG_Charge_Abbreviation_Missing_Report.Statute_Code IS NULL AND @statuteCode IS NULL)) AND
                                dbo.SLG_Charge_Abbreviation_Missing_Report.Product_Category_id = @productCategoryId
                IF(@@ROWCOUNT = 0)
                BEGIN
                INSERT INTO dbo.SLG_Charge_Abbreviation_Missing_Report VALUES(@OriginalChargeAbbreviation,@jurisdictionId,@OriginalStatuteCode,@productCategoryId,GETDATE(),GETDATE(),1);
                END
            commit
        END
    SELECT TOP 0 * FROM dbo.SLG_Charge_Mapping

END
```

Comment: Can you check wait_type information? You can get it from sys.dm_exec_requests table.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're trying to use some version of [Sam Saffron's upsert method](https://samsaffron.com/blog/archive/2007/04/04/14.aspx).

To take advantage of the [Key-Range Locking](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191272(v=sql.105).aspx) when using `holdlock`/`serializable` you need to have an index that covers the columns in the query.

If you don't have one that covers this query, you could consider creating one like this:

```
create unique nonclustered index ux_slg_Charge_Abbreviation_Missing_Report_jid_pcid_ca_sc
  on dbo.slg_Charge_Abbreviation_Missing_Report (
      Jurisdiction_id 
    , Product_Category_id
    , Charge_Abbreviation
    , Statute_Code
    );
```

I don't think the line: `set transaction isolation level read committed;` is doing you any favors in this instance.

```
set nocount on;
set xact_abort on;
if(@recordCount = 0 or @recordCount > 1 )
  begin;
    if @chargeAbbreviation is not null
      begin;
        begin tran;
            update camr with (updlock, serializable)
              set  camr.Occurrence_Count  = camr.Occurrence_Count + 1
                 , camr.ModifiedAt        = getdate()
              from dbo.slg_Charge_Abbreviation_Missing_Report as camr
            where camr.Jurisdiction_id            = @jurisdictionId 
              and camr.Product_Category_id        = @productCategoryId
              and upper(camr.Charge_Abbreviation) = @chargeAbbreviation 
              and (
                  upper(camr.Statute_Code)        = @statuteCode 
                    or (camr.Statute_Code is null and @statuteCode is null)
              ) 
        if @@rowcount = 0
          begin;
          insert into dbo.slg_Charge_Abbreviation_Missing_Report values
            (@OriginalChargeAbbreviation,@jurisdictionId
            ,@OriginalStatuteCode,@productCategoryId
            ,getdate(),getdate(),1);
          end;
        commit tran
      end;
    select top 0  from dbo.slg_Charge_Mapping;
end;
```

Note: `holdlock` is the same as `serializable`.

Links related to the solution above:

- [Insert or Update pattern for Sql Server - Sam Saffron](http://samsaffron.com/blog/archive/2007/04/04/14.aspx)
- [Key-Range Locking - MSDN](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191272(v=sql.105).aspx)
- [Documentation on serializable and other Table Hints - MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187373.aspx)
- [Error and Transaction Handling in SQL Server Part One – Jumpstart Error Handling - Erland Sommarskog](http://www.sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part1.html)
- [SQL Server Isolation Levels: A Series - Paul White](https://sqlperformance.com/2014/07/t-sql-queries/isolation-levels)
- [Simpletalk - SQL Server Deadlocks by Example - Gail Shaw](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/sql-server-deadlocks-by-example/)